# how to chain table in postgrestsql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, chaining

Can write a query for 2 This table is related to each other, how can the data be connected together in chains?

**table th01**

```
th1_id |         th1_datetime          | th1_temperature | th1_humidity |                          th1_hash
--------+-------------------------------+-----------------+--------------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | 2021-01-10 23:24:17.583604+07 | 27.0            | 22.0         | \xc5c249a9f9b493711f8cffd12747c64cfac70389a948aa31d677583bd9bd3bb8
      2 | 2021-01-10 23:36:38.074272+07 | 25.0            | 26.0         | \xeca7e916089363778221070cd21fa60a2e42085c36e68c37ee632ac67833154f
      3 | 2021-01-11 00:27:18.965292+07 | 26.0            | 26.0         | \xa6325b8f818927568a2efe390e67b7600d8692d3f99e293e4ede684e9abf3041
```

**table th02**

```
th2_id |                            th2_prevhash
--------+--------------------------------------------------------------------
      1 | \xc5c249a9f9b493711f8cffd12747c64cfac70389a948aa31d677583bd9bd3bb8
      2 | \xeca7e916089363778221070cd21fa60a2e42085c36e68c37ee632ac67833154f
      3 | \xa6325b8f818927568a2efe390e67b7600d8692d3f99e293e4ede684e9abf3041
```

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Answer (score 1):

The term you are looking for is *join* (not chaining). This is a key concept in relational database management systems (RDBMS).

The documentation you were looking for is here:
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-join.html